# Gridsplitter in statusbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, statusbar, gridsplitter

I am attempting to put grid splitters in a statusbar.  I have overridden the item panel template to place a grid in the status bar.  I want to be able to slide the grid columns back and forth.  Unfortunately I can't get the grid splitters to appear.  I am using the xaml code below.  Thanks for your time in advance.

```
<StatusBar>
            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid IsItemsHost="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Content="blah" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
                <GridSplitter Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <Label Content="blah1" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="3">
                <GridSplitter Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
                <Label Content="blah2" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="5">
                <GridSplitter Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="6">
                <Label Content="blah3" />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GridSplitter` is not a direct descendant of the `Grid`. It is wrapped in a `StatusBarItem`. Therefore this can't work in that configuration.

You could just use a `Grid` instead and style the background and borders to make it look like a `StatusBar`. The `StatusBar` is a relatively simple looking control, so it shouldn't be a too big of a deal to make something that looks like it.

Comment: When I remove the gridsplitter from within a status bar item I get the same functionality though.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this works just without the item wrapper. Since it seems to do the trick, great. :-)

Comment: Haha no I meant the grid splitter still doesn't appear when I wrap it in a statusbaritem, but it's fine.  A statusbar is fairly simple to recreate so I just styled a grid that looked similar.

Comment: Ah ok. That's what I suspected initially, hence the suggestion of restyling the grid.